# Which is the better option to handle errors between wait and sleep with selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

We sometimes use `sleep(10)` or sometimes as below:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
element = wait.until { driver.find_element :name => "search" }
element = driver.find_element :name => "search"
```

According to me with `wait` we set maximum timeout, during which if element is found (`<10 seconds`) we will move to the next line or if not found again also we would move to the next line but after 10 seconds as I set before.

But with `sleep()` we have to wait for program has to wait for `10 seconds` if the desired element loaded or not within that durations.

Both are generally used to prevent `element not found` error basically.

Now my questions are -

- *Is there any more difference between `wait` and `sleep`?*
- *Which one is better design to reduce the chance of errors?*
- *Is there any better implementation to handle such condition where we can handle such `element not found` error efficiently without failing the program?*

***EDIT***

For the last question I found one minimal risk code as below:

```
while true

 # do nothing

next if !(driver.title.include? "Buyer Home")

 driver.find_element(:link, "search").click
 break

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait.until` is not the same as `sleep` in terms of going to the next line. `wait.until` will throw an exception if the block (ex finding the element) is not found within the specified time frame.

The two methods have the same chance of reducing errors. If your sleep or timeout is set to 30 seconds and it takes the page 35 seconds to load the element, both will run into an error (though for different lines). The point of `wait.until` is so that if it takes the page only 5 seconds to load, you do not have to always wait 30 seconds.

I am not sure what implementation would be better than `wait.until`. If the element is not found, the program should fail. It makes more sense to fail immediately rather than waiting until later when something dependent on that field existing is run.

**Update**

As per comments, I would re-write

```
while true
  # do nothing
  next if !(driver.title.include? "Buyer Home")

  driver.find_element(:link, "search").click
  break
end
```

as

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { driver.title.include? "Buyer Home" }
driver.find_element(:link, "search").click
```

Comment: See my **EDIT**. Hope that make sense. If you have any better suggestion you are always welcome to give that. sometimes due to long time to get load the page, elements are not found. This is very basic problem with webpage automation I found in my case.

Comment: It looks like your EDIT is waiting indefinitely until the title appears and then clicking the element. I would have still used the `wait.until` and put the browser title check as the block. You could put a longer wait if the 10 seconds is not enough, but if the page is taking that long one would usually argue there is a bug with the page (I believe there was some article that users expect pages to load in 2 seconds or less).

Comment: does Rubu 2.0 suuports selenium-webdriver version `(2.31.0)`? any idea? I am getting error when doing `require "selenium-webdriver"`?

Comment: I have not tried myself. You might want to log a bug if it does not work.

Comment: Okay! as per your comments regarding this post,could you give me a code which you have suggested above?

Comment: the issue with Ruby 2.0. I just re-installed `ruby 1.9.3` now it is fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26261/discussion-between-iamrubuuu-and-justin-ko)